# I want to get Dofollow link without sending visitor on my site. anyone know the right code?

Tags: html, hyperlink

May be this is right code but it's not working in comment. 
anyone how know the right way please help me.

my code is :-

```
<p class="text"><a href="Source link" target="_blank">Source Keyword</a><a href="Our Site Link" target=_blank"</a></p>
```

Example :-

```
<p class="text"><a href="https://www.example.com/sometool/" target="_blank">some tool</a><a href="https://www.example.com/somepage/somesubpage/somesubsubpage/" target=_blank"</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting the '>' at the end of the second `<a>` tag. Try this:

```
<p class="text"><a href="Source link" target="_blank">Source Keyword</a><a href="Our Site Link" target=_blank"></a></p>
```